# How to use Python read numbers and skip the letters

Tags: python

For example, my txt file looks like this:

```
coke: 100
mineral water: 200
wine: 500
```

I just want python to read the numbers of each, thank you!

Comment: According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404053/13552470) post, we simply don't care if an asker showed their attempt, or made one for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    numbers = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if ':' in line:
            numbers.append(int(line.split(':')[1]))
```

You could even use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    numbers = [int(line.split(':')[1]) for line in f.readlines() if ':' in line]
```

---

If there will be lines of different format, you can try using the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
     numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', f.read())
```

And you can convert the list of strings into integers using the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
     numbers = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', f.read())))
```

Comment: It'd be index 1

Comment: @SamDolan Thank you!